# increase or specify gap into .text section in compiled executable to add assembly code manually

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, assembly, executable, execution

I have little experience modifying applications in assembly level without recompiling them. 
First i have to find a big enough gap that does not change at runtime, add some code, and modify existing code to let new code execute.
But there is no guarantee that free space for new code is found, maybe there is a way to generate it?

I have created a template code in c++, of course, i compiled it, but there is no much free space to work in. I created large array `char SharedSection[1024*1024]`, but free space appears in `.data` file (checked with 7zip). Am i true i can not let code in .data execute? How can i generate free space into `.text`?

Any help appreciated!

---

## Edit:

Main purpose is to edit code in assembly level when c/c++ code is not available or it is not coded in that programming language. This applies to already compiled executables (whatever i compiled it or not). I created template to test where `char SharedSection[1024*1024]` goes.

---

## Edit 2:

I got it working (thanks User.1) with this code:

```
//Your headers

void ReservedCode(void);

//Your code

#ifndef _DEBUG
#pragma optimize( "", off )
#endif

void ReservedCode(void){
__asm{ 
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    ;how many bytes you want?
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP};
}
#ifndef _DEBUG
#pragma optimize( "", on )
#endif
```

But i still have no idea, what to do with already compiled code (reassemble .text?)!

Comment: I don't understand.  Why do you need to reserve space for assembly language?  Most projects rebuild and let the linker handle the placement of assembly code.

Comment: @DjJeshk Is this on an x86 machine ?  x64 ?

Comment: @User.1 i have x86 machine

Comment: @ThomasMatthews see edits. I just need a tool that makes changes in already compiled executable.

Comment: @DjJeshk I have no idea if this will work, I've never had your problem before, so, it's just something to try: See what happens if you put 50 or 100 `NOP` instructions right after another. See if the complier "helps" you out and removes them for you.  Would that give you some space as you want ?

Comment: There is no guaranteed method to reserve code or execution space using the **standard** C++ language.  You need to tell the linker to reserve space.  Many will do this with *incremental linking*.  Your `SharedSection` is occupying space in the **data** area.  I have done this before, but with linkers or assembly language files.

Comment: In the olden days, we used to reserve extra space in the executable region for making machine code changes during development because we either didn't have the source code or the compilation phase was very expensive.  The technique we used was to read the linker manual and set up the command file to reserve space, or use an assembly language file that allocated space in the code section (a.k.a. .text).

Comment: @User.1 inline assembly with `NOP`'s works well!

Comment: @DjJeshk would you like me to write it as an answer ?

Comment: @User.1 If you write this and reason why is not acceptable to increase size of executable .text section, I will happily accept it. Just found out that reference to char arrays that point to .data section is constant.

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods to reserve space, many are tool dependent.

If you want to use C++ to reserve space, you will need to add the keyword "volatile" to the array, so that the compiler doesn't discard it and the linker doesn't remove it.

Many compilers will remove code that isn't used.  They may also remove variables that are not accessed.

Linkers may eliminate code that isn't referenced and variables that are not referenced.

So, if you need to reserve some space tag the variable as volatile:
  volatile uint8_t reserved[1024 * 1024];

I don't recommend using the C++ language for reserving space.  I believe a better method is to let the Linker reserve the space.

You have less control by using C++ for placement of the reserved area than with Linker commands.  In standard C++, you can reserve the space but you can't tell the tool where to put it.

Most linkers have a command language that allows you to declare sections or segments, where they will locate and their sizes.  Some tool packages have extended sequence that lets you assign C++ variables to sections or segments.

If you want to reserve room in the code area, you will have to supply commands to the Linker, or create an assembly language file.  There is no standard C++ facility to reserve executable space.

If you create a stub function to reserve space, the compiler or linker may drop it because it is not used.  Check out the documentation for your linker.

Comment: see edit 2. It is possible to tell C++ to not remove useless function using pragma and dont care about linker's command line. Do you know how to generate free space in already compiled file?